# Can I take snapshot of unhealthy instance before AWS Autoscale group terminates it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I have a 3 node cluster of ec2 instances controlled by ASG. When any of application server running on an ec2 misbehaves, the elb health check fails and hence asg terminates it and recreates a new instance. So in a way my setup is self healing however, I would like to debug more into instance while this is happening. I would like to have a snapshot or ami of misbehaving instance so that i can dive deep into the issue.

Any suggestions how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DetachInstances**

The best method would be to call [`detach-instances`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/detach-instance-asg.html#detach-instance-aws-cli), which removes an instance from the Auto Scaling group and optionally replaces it.

However, it would not be easy to trigger this command after a health check has failed.

**Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hook**

You could configure an [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html), which will get called before an instance is terminated. Your lifecycle hook could then snapshot the volume. However, I'm not sure whether a lifecycle termination hook is called when the health check fails (as opposed to when a scale-in event occurs), so this would require some testing.

**CloudWatch triggering Lambda**

Another option would be:

- Do *not* configure Auto Scaling to use the Load Balancer health check
- If an instance fails the ELB health check, then ELB will not send traffic to the instance, so your app is still okay
- Use a CloudWatch Alarm to trigger a Lambda function when the number of unhealthy instances attached to the ELB is greater than zero
- The Lambda function could check statuses to determine which instance is unhealthy, then call `detach-instances` to remove it from the Auto Scaling group
- Thus, you have access to the unhealthy instance, outside of the Auto Scaling group, without even having to play around with EBS snapshots

Comment: I will explore ASG life cycle hook, thanks for your detailed feedback.

Comment: asg lifecycle is not called when an instance terminates, it only gets called when there is a proper scale in... i thought that would be the normal behaviour :(